# Critical section containing another critical section?

Tags: c++, multithreading, critical-section

Is it permissible to nest critical section like this below?:

```
void somefunction()
{
   EnterCriticalSection(&g_List); 
   ...
   EnterCriticalSection(&g_Variable); 
   ...

   LeaveCriticalSection(&g_Variable);  
   ...
   LeaveCriticalSection(&g_List);
}
```

Comment: @SamCristall: `CRITICAL_SECTION`s may be acquired recursively.  But you do need to mind lock ordering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable.  It is the norm for any slightly complicated program to have many layers of nesting in places.

The one thing you need to be aware of is that you must always take locks in the same order.

If you don't do this, you risk deadlocks in scenarios like

Thread A runs code like:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&g_List); 
EnterCriticalSection(&g_Variable); 
...
LeaveCriticalSection(&g_Variable);  
LeaveCriticalSection(&g_List);
```

but thread B runs

```
EnterCriticalSection(&g_Variable); 
EnterCriticalSection(&g_List); 
...
LeaveCriticalSection(&g_List);
LeaveCriticalSection(&g_Variable);
```

This risks a deadlock where thread A locks `g_List` then blocks waiting on `g_Variable` while thread B has locked `g_Variable` and is blocked waiting on `g_List`